# XPath - Duplicating results based on tag counts

Tags: html, xpath, html-table, duplicates

I have a table that I would like to enter into a spreadsheet/database by duplicating the title based on the number of rows within a sub-table.

I would like to avoid post-processing if possible, so I'm looking for an XPath expression that does this.

For example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title One</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Row one</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row Four</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From above, is there an XPath expression that would return 'Title One' 4 times, based on the number of tr//td tags in the subtable? For example:

```
Title One
Title One
Title One
Title One
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 2.0 or 3.0 can do that in a single expression:

```
for $r in 1 to count(/table/tr[2]/td/table/tr/td) return /table/tr[1]/th/string()
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thank you!

Comment: XPath 2.0 exist since 2007 and has a `for` expression http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily programmaticaly; here I use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), but the logic can be used in any language of your choice :

```
count=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//td[starts-with(text(), "Row")])' table.html)
for ((i=0; i<count; i++)) {
    xmllint --xpath '//table/tr/th/text()' table.html
    echo
}
```

#### OUTPUT :

```
Title One
Title One
Title One
Title One
```

Comment: Thanks, I only had XPath available at the time, so I couldn't do it this way